# How to set phpmyadmin to use the filename as the Table Name when importing a CSV?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

If I import mydatabase.csv into phpmyadmin as a new table, it will automatically be renamed to 'TABLE XX' (where XX is the next consecutive table number. How do I set it to use the filename 'mydatabase' as the title for the table?

When doing this, I'd also like to set it to 'Use first line of the file as column names' by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a command string and execute it using prepared statements, e.g.:

```
SET @file_name = 'data1';  -- file name, without extension

SET @sql = CONCAT(
'LOAD DATA INFILE ', @file_name, '.csv INTO TABLE ', @file_name, 
' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '';'' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\r'' IGNORE 1 LINES');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```